# Why is the program not exiting but printing? (Python)

Tags: python, printing

This code is printing 'test' but it is not closing the program? It is also not printing 'test2'. What is causing it and how can I fix it? sys.exit() is working in other sections in my program but for some reason not in this one.

```
def fivesec():
    global  number
    number = int(number)
    if number != 0:
        number = number - 1
        number = str(number)
        label.configure(text = "Sucess, closing in" + number + "seconds")
        t = Timer(1, fivesec)
        t.start()
    else :
        print ("test")
        sys.exit()
        print ("test2")
```